# array to object javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

[image]

so i get a row from a an array but the value i get is still an array. i already tried to assign it to an object but the object still contain an array. how can i make it like the 2nd line where the arrow is pointed?

```js
var profile = $(this).data('profile');
var citizens = $(this).data('citizens');
console.log(citizens);
console.log(profile);

var keys = $.map(citizens, function(value, key) {
  var r;
  if (value.id == 4) {
    r = value

  }
  return r;
});
console.log(keys);
var zxcv = Object.assign({}, keys);
console.log(zxcv);
```

Comment: Please update the snippet to be a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

use `find` or `filter()[0]` instead of `map`.

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

[array.map MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)